# Cakephp meta tags not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using the following cakephp format to give meta tags for all my pages. But unfortunately I can able to see meta description only for home page, for other pages I couldn't able to see any meta description and keywords.

```
<?php $this->Html->meta("keywords","kw, kw, kw,", array("inline" => false)); ?> 


<?php $this->Html->meta("description","Meta description", array("inline" => false)); ?>
```

Comment: You maybe use different layouts for home page and other pages

Comment: Yes! I'm using different layout for other pages. Please don't mind, I'm new to cakephp, so can you tell me how to give meta tags for other pages in this situation?

Comment: Is meta data same on all pages?

Comment: Read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html

Comment: Yes. Meta tags are same on all pages.

Comment: Have you tried my solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

Add echo before each call

```
<?php echo $this->Html->meta("keywords","kw, kw, kw,", array("inline" => false)); ?> 


<?php echo $this->Html->meta("description","Meta description", array("inline" => false)); ?>
```